# D3 update pattern drawing the same element twice

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I’ve created a line graph in D3. To ensure the line doesn’t overlap the y-axis, I have altered the range of the x-axis. As a result of this, there is a gap between the x-axis and the y-axis which I am trying to fill with another line.

The rest of the graph uses the D3 update pattern. However, when I try to use the pattern on this simple line, two path elements are drawn (one on top of the other). I have tried numerous solutions to correct this issue but I’m not having any luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The code below is what is drawing two of the same path elements

```
var xAxisLineData = [
    { x: margins.left     , y: height - margins.bottom + 0.5 },
    { x: margins.left + 40, y: height - margins.bottom + 0.5 }];

var xAxisLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; });

    var update = vis.selectAll(".xAxisLine")
                 .data(xAxisLineData);

    var enter = update.enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", xAxisLine(xAxisLineData))
                .attr("class", "xAxisLine")
                .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Comment: Can you post HTML part ?

Comment: That code lives in a JS file which is called in the HTML. Do you want the HTML code or what is shown when I inspect the elements?

Comment: Try to reproduce it with JS Fiddle

Comment: Most probably you want `.attr("d", xAxisLine)`, not `.attr("d", xAxisLine(xAxisLineData))`.

Comment: That was the first solution I tried but it results in no path elements being drawn

Comment: What is in your xAxisLineData? Two points?

Comment: Yes, it's the coordinates that a line has to be drawn between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
var update = vis.selectAll(".xAxisLine")
             .data(xAxisLineData);
```

this is a null selection, assuming there are no elements with the class `xAxisLine`, which means that using `.enter().append()` will append one element for each item in the `xAxisLineData` array.

You want to append one path per set of points representing a line, not one path for each in a set of points representing a line.

You really just want one line to be drawn, so you could do:

```
.data([xAxisLineData]);
```

or, place all the points in an array when defining `xAxisLineData`

Now you are passing a data array to the selection that contains one item: an array of points - as opposed to many items representing individual points. As the data array has one item, and your selection is empty, using `.enter().append()` will append one element:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height",400);

var lineData = [{x:100,y:100},{x:200,y:200}]

var xAxisLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; });
                
var colors = ["steelblue","orange"];
  
var line = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([lineData])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", xAxisLine(lineData))
  .attr("class", "xAxisLine")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d,i) { return (1-i) * 10 + 10; })
  .attr("stroke", function(d,i) { return colors[i]; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Compare without using an array to hold all the data points:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height",400);

var lineData = [{x:100,y:100},{x:200,y:200}]

var xAxisLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; });
                
var colors = ["steelblue","orange"];
  
var line = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(lineData)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", xAxisLine(lineData))
  .attr("class", "xAxisLine")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d,i) { return (1-i) * 10 + 10; })
  .attr("stroke", function(d,i) { return colors[i]; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But, we can make one last change. Since each item in the data array is bound to the element, we can reference the datum, not the data array `xAxisLineData`, which would make adding multiple lines much easier:

`.attr("d", function(d) { return xAxisLine(d) })`

*Note in the demo below that the variable `xAxisLineData` is defined as an array of arrays of points, or an array of multiple lines.*

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height",400);

var lineData = [[{x:100,y:100},{x:200,y:200}],[{x:150,y:150},{x:260,y:150}]]

var xAxisLine = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; });
                
var colors = ["steelblue","orange"];
  
var line = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(lineData)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return xAxisLine(d) }) // use the element's datum 
  .attr("class", "xAxisLine")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d,i) { return (1-i) * 10 + 10; })
  .attr("stroke", function(d,i) { return colors[i]; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful! Exactly what I needed with all of the reasoning explained well